# Programmatically add options to pulldown button in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In eclipse I have commands defined for buttons in the main button toolbar they have.  I have one command/button in there that's set as a pulldown button and I'd like to programmatically add options to it.  Kinda like how you can hit the little drop down button on the play button in eclipse and see different run scenarios.  I want to be able to add options like that to my pulldown menu. I can't do it through the plugin editor because I need to generate the menu options dynamically.

So say I have the following pulldown button defined in my plugin.xml file.  How do I add options to the pull down programmatically?

```
 <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
     <toolbar
           id="com.company.gui.base.toolBarMain">
        <command
              commandId="com.company.gui.base.command1"
              icon="icons/magnifier.png"
              id="com.company.gui.base.toolBarMain.monitor"
              label="Im a pulldown menu"
              style="pulldown">
        </command>
     </toolbar>
  </menuContribution>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please find the below code.

```
private void addContextMenu(SampleContributionFactory fac) {
     final IMenuService menuService = (IMenuService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService (IMenuService.class);
     menuService.addContributionFactory(fac);
}

class SampleContributionFactory extends AbstractContributionFactory{

    SampleContributionFactory(final String menuID) {
        super("menu:" + menuID, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void createContributionItems(IServiceLocator serviceLocator,
            IContributionRoot additions) {      
        // add Command Contribution item
        additions.addContributionItem(<YOUR CONTRIBUTION ITEM>, null);
    // add one more Command Contribution item
    ....
    } 
}
```

Now create an object of SampleContributionFactory as below.

```
  SampleContributionFactory fac = new SampleContributionFactory ("com.company.gui.base.toolBarMain.monitor");
```

and call the method

```
addContextMenu(fac);
```

TODO : add command contribution items in the SampleContributionFactory  as required by you.

Comment: Are there any tutorials on this in the eclipse documentation?  It seems that they document pretty well everything that can be done declaratively, but when a dynamic/programmatic approach to the framework is needed, I can never find the right info.  Your solution works great, but after digging through and trying lots of various things in the API documentation, I got nowhere with it until you came along.

Comment: Some of the links which might help you are : http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/IFile_objectContribution and http://www.medihack.org/2009/10/05/dynamic-menus-and-toolbar-contributions/.
But you are correct, somethings are very difficult to find the documentation. Only way we have to get is by digging the eclipse source code itself. :-)

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/Problems_View_Example might help too