# How to update a drop down list of a pull down button in the Eclipse toolbar?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, toolbar

I have added a drop down list dynamically to a pull down button in the Eclipse toolbar, by following the instructions: [Programmatically add options to pulldown button in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841838/programmatically-add-options-to-pulldown-button-in-eclipse)

Now, I need to update the drop down list. My idea is to remove the old list and then add a new list to the pull down button. I tried the methods: removeContributionFactory(AbstractContributionFactory factory) and dispose() of IMenuService, but none of them works. Could anyone give me some tips of how to achieve the goal?

Here is the code that I used:

(1) in class A, I invoke the method to add a drop down list to the pull down button (command)

```
Class A {
 public static ContextSwitchContributionFactory contextFactory = 
  new ContextSwitchContributionFactory("menu:"+"SwitchContext", null);
 public static IMenuService menuService =
  (IMenuService)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IMenuService.class);

 ...
 method A () {
 ...
 ContextSwitchContributionFactory.updateContextMenu(menuService, contextFactory, "SwitchContext");
 ...
 }
```

(2) the definition of ContextSwitchContributionFactory:

```
public class ContextSwitchContributionFactory extends
AbstractContributionFactory {
  private ContextData contextData = new ContextData();
  private ContextsCollector contextList; 
}

static public void updateContextMenu (IMenuService service, final AbstractContributionFactory       factory, final String menuId) {

  service.dispose();
  service.addContributionFactory(factory); 
} 


public ContextSwitchContributionFactory(String location, String namespace) {
  super(location, namespace);
  // this is to read the file and update the data for creating the drop down list   
  contextData.readContextsFile();
  contextList = contextData.getContextsCollector();
} 

@Override
public void createContributionItems(IServiceLocator serviceLocator,
  IContributionRoot additions) {

Set<IContext> cxtset = contextList.getContextList();
Iterator<IContext> iterator = cxtset.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {

  IContext context = iterator.next();
  CommandContributionItemParameter menuitem = new CommandContributionItemParameter(
      serviceLocator, null, 
      "coms.sample.command.context",
      CommandContributionItem.STYLE_PUSH);    

  menuitem.label = context.getName();
  menuitem.visibleEnabled = true;

  if (context.isSelected()) {
     ImageDescriptor image = MechanicPlugin.getImageDescriptor("icons/ticking_icon.png");
     menuitem.icon = image;
  }

  additions.addContributionItem(new CommandContributionItem(menuitem), null);
  } 
 }
}
```

(3) in the method C of class C, I want to update the drop down list:

```
class C {
...
method C {
...
  // A.menuService.dispose(); (doesn't work)
  // remove the old one
  A.menuService.removeContributionFactory(A.contextFactory);
  // create a new one 
  A.contextFactory = 
    new ContextSwitchContributionFactory("menu:"+"SwitchContext", null);
  // after executing this statement, the old drop down list is still there, and the new one is             added after the old list.
  A.menuService.addContributionFactory(A.contextFactory);
  ContextSwitchContributionFactory.updateContextMenu(menuService, contextFactory,      "SwitchContext");
..
```

Comment: anyone knows how to update it?

Comment: put code you tried with

Comment: Hi, I have added the code that I used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the answer, the method I used, for nature, the drop down list cannot be updated. To add a drop down list that can be refreshed, dynamic elements should be used: [Static and dynamic pulldown menus](http://codeandme.blogspot.sg/2013/01/static-and-dynamic-pulldown-menus.html)